# Hibernate 6 JdbcTypeCode can not convert bytea to String[] array

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

As I am migrating from Spring boot 2.5 to 3.0 - it updated Hibernate to 6.0. I have a field in Java entity which stored as bytea in PostgreSQL database. And I am reading back in the String[].

To fix this issue, I use @JdbcTypeCode annotation and tried to read the value but it is not working.

> The problem is @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.Array) can not convert bytea to
> String[]

```
  @Column(name = "dummy")
  @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.ARRAY)
  private String[] dummy;
```

With the SqlTypes.Array I am getting below exception

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to extract JDBC value for position `3`

According to http://www.java2s.com/example/java-api/java/sql/types/array-0.html
SqlTypes.Array returns Object[] but if I change from String[] to Object[] I am getting below error at compile time.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.CollectionJavaType cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BasicPluralJavaType (org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.CollectionJavaType and org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BasicPluralJavaType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

**Alternative Approach tried**

I tried getting the data in byte[] like below,

```
  @Column(name = "dummy")
  private byte[] dummy;
  
  public String[] getDummy() {
    SerializationUtils.deserialize(dummy); //This is deprecated
  }
```

**And tried converting using SerializationUtils but the deserialize method is deprecated and when with ObjectInputStream we are getting SecurityHotspot.**

Looking for a lead on how I can convert stored bytea in postgres db to String[]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot think of an obvious conversion from a hex-encoded binary string to an array of `String`.  Could you explain how you would want that conversion to be done?  (Even converting `bytea` to a `String` is a bit dubious ... since you are not specifying what encoding scheme should be used to decode the binary string.)

Comment: So encoding schema should be UTF-8. But that might not be concern here, as with @JdbcTypeCode I am able to convert Java objects but it has some issues with Object arrays.

Comment: What makes most sense to be is to try to map a `bytea` to a `byte[]` and then decode the `byte[]` yourself in code as appropriate.  That is, using a decoding scheme that is the reverse of the scheme used to encode the data before storing it in the database.

Comment: You haven't addressed the real question.  How is the `bytea` actually encoded?  Unless you know that, I don't know how you can expect Hibernate to understand what to do.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of byte[]. I have updated my question. I already tried that but the problem is we can not use deserializer as it's method is deprecated. Alternative way has a security hotspot. And we didn't use and encoding while converting to String[] to byte[] it is default UTF-8